# Index Key Column Order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, index, primary-key

I have created a joining table for many-to-many relationship.

The table only has 2 cols in it, `ticketid` and `groupid`

typical data would be

```
groupid    ticketid
20         56  
20         87
20         96
24         13
24         87
25         5
```

My question is when creating the composite key should I have `ticketid` followed by `groupid`

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_ticketgroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
        [ticketid] ASC,
        [groupid] ASC
    )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Or the other way, `groupid` followed by `ticketid`

```
CONSTRAINT [PK_ticketgroup] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        (
            [groupid] ASC,
                    [ticketid] ASC
        )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Would searching the index be quicker in option 1 as the `ticketid` has more chance of being unique then the `groupid` and they would be at the start of the composite key? Or is this negligible?

Comment: In a joining table like this, one usually has both indexes. Now, which one of the two should be clustered, is an interesting question.

Comment: It depends on what query you are using (the most). Do you want to find groups belonging to a ticket or do you want to find tickets belonging to a group? If you only want to find one row given the values of the primary key you should have the most selective column first. @ypercube In the case with two indexes I don't think it would matter which one is clustered or...? The second is covering so it should be enough.

Comment: @Mikael: I meant it might matter (and be an interesting question) for INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE efficiency and for fragmentation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This all depends on how exactly you are retrieving data from this clustered index.  The clustered index will be sorted by the leading key column, followed by sorting on each subsequent key column as defined in the index definition.  The best way to see this is through an example.

---

## Test Object Setup

```
use TestDB;
go

if exists (select 1 from sys.tables where name = 'TestTable2')
begin
    drop table TestTable2;
end
create table TestTable2
(
    groupid int not null,
    ticketid int not null
);
go

insert into TestTable2(groupid, ticketid)
values
    (20, 56),  
    (20, 87),
    (20, 96),
    (24, 13),
    (24, 87),
    (25, 5 );
go
```

### Test 1 (groupid, ticketid) Key Column Order

Now let's create the clustered index defined on the key columns `(groupid, ticketid)`:

```
alter table TestTable2
add constraint PK_TestTable2
primary key clustered (groupid, ticketid);
go
```

Now we want to look at how this data is stored in the page:

```
dbcc ind('TestDB', 'TestTable2', 1);
go
-- FileID:1 PageID:310

if exists (select 1 from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#DbccPage%')
begin
    drop table #DbccPage;
end
create table #DbccPage
(
    ParentObject varchar(128) null,
    Object varchar(128) null,
    Field varchar(128) null,
    Value varchar(128) null
);
go

insert into #DbccPage
exec ('dbcc page(TestDB, 1, 310, 3) with tableresults;');
go

select
    Object,
    Field,
    Value
from #DbccPage
where ParentObject not in
(
    'page header:',
    'buffer:'
)
and Object not like 'memory dump%';
```

[image]

We see that it is in fact sorted by `groupid` first, then `ticketid`.  This will result in the follow query being an index seek:

```
-- this is an index seek
select *
from TestTable2
where groupid = 25;
```

[image]

And this query will be a scan because it can't seek on `ticketid`:

```
-- this is an index scan
select *
from TestTable2
where ticketid = 13;
```

[image]

### Test 2 (ticketid, groupid) Key Column Order

But now let's change it up and swap the order of key columns:

```
alter table TestTable2
drop constraint PK_TestTable2;
go

alter table TestTable2
add constraint PK_TestTable2
primary key clustered (ticketid, groupid);
go
```

Now let's take a look at how the data is on the index page:

```
dbcc ind('TestDB', 'TestTable2', 1);
go
-- FileID:1 PageID:308

if exists (select 1 from tempdb.sys.tables where name like '#DbccPage%')
begin
    drop table #DbccPage;
end
create table #DbccPage
(
    ParentObject varchar(128) null,
    Object varchar(128) null,
    Field varchar(128) null,
    Value varchar(128) null
);
go

insert into #DbccPage
exec ('dbcc page(TestDB, 1, 308, 3) with tableresults;');
go

select
    Object,
    Field,
    Value
from #DbccPage
where ParentObject not in
(
    'page header:',
    'buffer:'
)
and Object not like 'memory dump%';
```

[image]

Now we see that the data is sorted by `ticketid` first, then `groupid`.  This will change the behavior of our test queries as follows:

```
-- this is an index scan
select *
from TestTable2
where groupid = 25;
```

[image]

```
-- this is an index seek
select *
from TestTable2
where ticketid = 13;
```

[image]

### Summary

So as you can see above, it boils down to your workload and the kind of queries that are hitting this clustered index.  It's the different between being able to seek based off of the `WHERE` clause (or a `JOIN`) or scan depending on the sequential ordering of the key columns and how they are defined.

Comment: +1 for `dbcc ind` and `dbcc page` that I haven't seen before.

Comment: @Wojteq They are undocumented.  See here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlserverstorageengine/archive/2006/12/13/more-undocumented-fun_3a00_-dbcc-ind_2c00_-dbcc-page_2c00_-and-off_2d00_row-columns.aspx